# Create Table As Select in Impala with NULL column

Tags: sql, parquet, impala

**Context**

I select some data from a table and initialize a dummy-column for a join with `NULL`.

```sql
SELECT
    col_a as a,
    NULL  as b
FROM dummy_table;

-- Output
+---+----+
| a | b  |
+---+----+
| 1 |NULL|
|...|NULL|
+---+----+
```

This works and produces a correct output.

**Problem**

I want to store that output in a table to do further processing.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_table STORED AS parquet AS
    SELECT
        col_a as a,
        NULL  as b
    FROM dummy_table;
```

While the first query runs, the second does not and fails with the following error:

> AnalysisException: Unsupported type 'null_type' in column 'b' of table 'temp_table' CAUSED BY: TableLoadingException: Unsupported type 'null_type' in column 'b' of table 'temp_table'

*Why does the table creation fail while the select-part is actually working?*

Comment: Since you provide only NULL, the DB can not determince which data type you want for that new table column. Try casting the NULL value to the type you want

Comment: Nice, that's the solution! :) Interestingly, when just executing the query Impala casts it as boolean itself, but the table creation wants a specifc type. Post your comment as answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you provide only `NULL` as value your DB can not determince which data type you want for that new table column.

Just cast the `NULL` value to the type you want.